# Broken usage of portable interceptors for local objects in JacORB 3.x?

Tags: java, interceptor, corba, jacorb

The implementation how portable interceptors are used for local objects has changed in JacORB 3, as 
stated in the release notes: "*Implemented portable interceptors correctly for local objects.*"
It seems that this new implementation causes some issues; the easiest way to reproduce the problem
is to modify the GssUpServer.java from the sas-demo (the one that comes with the jacorb):

```
public class GssUpServer extends SASDemoPOA {

        private ORB orb;
        private boolean calledPrintSAS = false; // added

        public GssUpServer(ORB orb) {
            this.orb = orb;
        }

        public void printSAS() {
            try {
                org.omg.PortableInterceptor.Current current = (org.omg.PortableInterceptor.Current) orb
                        .resolve_initial_references("PICurrent");
                org.omg.CORBA.Any anyName = current
                        .get_slot(org.jacorb.security.sas.SASInitializer.sasPrincipalNamePIC);
                if (anyName.type().kind().value() == org.omg.CORBA.TCKind._tk_null) {
                    System.out.println("Null Name");
                } else {
                    String name = anyName.extract_string();
                    System.out.println("printSAS for user " + name);
                }

                // /* added
                if (!calledPrintSAS) {
                    calledPrintSAS = true;                    
                    // local call, (JacORB 3.x: throws NPE from SASClientInterceptor)
                    _this().printSAS();
                }
                // */
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
...
}
```

Stacktrace after the GssUpClient.bat:

```
2013-04-11 11:01:24.968 SEVERE unexpected exception during servant_preinvoke              org.jacorb.security.sas.SASClientInterceptor.send_request(SASClientInterceptor.java:194)
org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ClientInterceptorIterator.invoke(ClientInterceptorIterator.java:129)
org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.AbstractInterceptorIterator.iterate(AbstractInterceptorIterator.java:66)
org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ClientInterceptorIterator.iterate(ClientInterceptorIterator.java:87)
org.jacorb.orb.DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.invokeInterceptors(DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.java:328)
org.jacorb.orb.DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.handle_send_request(DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.java:132)
org.jacorb.orb.Delegate.servant_preinvoke(Delegate.java:2505)
org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._servant_preinvoke(ObjectImpl.java:135)
org.jacorb.demo.sas._SASDemoStub.printSAS(_SASDemoStub.java:73)
org.jacorb.demo.sas.GssUpServer.printSAS(GssUpServer.java:46)
org.jacorb.demo.sas.SASDemoPOA._invoke(SASDemoPOA.java:47)
org.jacorb.poa.RequestProcessor.invokeOperation(RequestProcessor.java:348)
org.jacorb.poa.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:670)
org.jacorb.poa.RequestProcessor.run(RequestProcessor.java:820)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jacorb.security.sas.SASClientInterceptor.send_request(SASClientInterceptor.java:194)
    at org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ClientInterceptorIterator.invoke(ClientInterceptorIterator.java:129)
    at org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.AbstractInterceptorIterator.iterate(AbstractInterceptorIterator.java:66)
    at org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ClientInterceptorIterator.iterate(ClientInterceptorIterator.java:87)
    at org.jacorb.orb.DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.invokeInterceptors(DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.java:328)
    at org.jacorb.orb.DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.handle_send_request(DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.java:132)
    at org.jacorb.orb.Delegate.servant_preinvoke(Delegate.java:2505)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._servant_preinvoke(ObjectImpl.java:135)
    at org.jacorb.demo.sas._SASDemoStub.printSAS(_SASDemoStub.java:73)
    at org.jacorb.demo.sas.GssUpServer.printSAS(GssUpServer.java:46)
    at org.jacorb.demo.sas.SASDemoPOA._invoke(SASDemoPOA.java:47)
    at org.jacorb.poa.RequestProcessor.invokeOperation(RequestProcessor.java:348)
    at org.jacorb.poa.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:670)
    at org.jacorb.poa.RequestProcessor.run(RequestProcessor.java:820)
```

Above code works perfectly well in JacORB 2.3.1. Simple workaround for this problem would be setting the property `jacorb.isLocalHistoricalInterceptors` to true; 
however, certain "built-in" methods (e.g. `_is_a()`) do not respect this flag (since those methods check the object locality directly using `is_really_local()`). It seems
that these "built-in" method calls have never before been using the interceptors when the call is made locally.

**So my observations are:**

1. JacORB 3.x seems to break some portable interceptors for local calls (to be precise, interceptors that need connection-object...)
2. JacORB 3.x seems to be the first JacORB to use portable interceptors for local calls made to `_is_a()`, `_non_existent()`, `_interface()`, `_get_component()`

First issue is solvable, since there is a property that makes the JacORB 3.x work as the older versions. Second one (combined with the first one) seems really troublesome.

**Has anyone else noticed this kind of behaviour, and can verify my suspect that this is indeed a defect in JacORB 3.x, or have I missed something?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built in portable interceptors with local calls should work correctly; this sounds like a bug. In fact it sounds like [Using AMI+BiDir with jacorb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537635/using-amibidir-with-jacorb). I have also entered http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=957

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't see this hence the late reply; please note the official JacORB mailing lists are here : http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html and the bugzilla is http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla

Comment: Thanks! We did a quick patch for this in our software, and after that I kinda forgot this issue. I probably should have used your bugzilla right away :)