# Using AMI+BiDir with jacorb

Tags: amazon-ami, jacorb

Does it possible to use simultaneously AMI and BiDir features with jacorb? 
Both work for me, but would not work together.
Examples, coming with jacorb demonstrates either  BiDir or AMI.

The error that I see is following:

```
    SEVERE: Unexpected error during receiveMessages. Lost a message!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rg.jacorb.orb.giop.BiDirConnectionClientInterceptor.send_request(BiDirConnectionClientInterceptor.java:125)
    at org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ClientInterceptorIterator.invoke(ClientInterceptorIterator.java:129)
    at org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.AbstractInterceptorIterator.iterate(AbstractInterceptorIterator.java:66)
    at org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ClientInterceptorIterator.iterate(ClientInterceptorIterator.java:87)
    at org.jacorb.orb.DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.invokeInterceptors(DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.java:328)
    at org.jacorb.orb.DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.handle_send_request(DefaultClientInterceptorHandler.java:132)
    at org.jacorb.orb.Delegate.servant_preinvoke(Delegate.java:2505)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ReplyReceiver.performCallback(ReplyReceiver.java:240)
    at org.jacorb.orb.ReplyReceiver.replyReceived(ReplyReceiver.java:183)
    at org.jacorb.orb.giop.ClientConnection.replyReceived(ClientConnection.java:355)
    at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessagesLoop(GIOPConnection.java:820)
    at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessages(GIOPConnection.java:527)
    at org.jacorb.orb.giop.MessageReceptor.doWork(MessageReceptor.java:69)
    at org.jacorb.util.threadpool.ConsumerTie.run(ConsumerTie.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

please, advise.

UPD: I modified AMI example from jacorb's demo, added BiDir functionality (copied from BiDir example) and now synchronious calls work but ansync (AMI) do not.

Answer (score 0):

They should work together. This does look like a possible issue. Are you using local calls? Can you please provide your test case and submit a ticket on http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla/

(Please note the official JacORB mailing lists are here : http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html )

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

I added BiDir options to AMI example, comming with jacorb's demos and got same error. But i am not sure that this is a bug, rather then my personal stupidity. 

Also, I asked this question on official mailing list, but still no answer.

Comment: Apologies I missed your question on the developer list. I'll follow up there. I have managed to reproduce it locally. I suspect it is a bug in local calls.